# python requests get https lead to a memory leak, both on win10 and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, https, memory-leaks, python-requests

I find a memory leak on this simplest situation,on win10 and ubuntu 16.04,but only when you request a https protocol,if it is a http protocol, there is no memory leak

```
import requests
while 1:
    with requests.get('https://www.baidu.com') as r:
        text = r.text
```

I try to use gc, objgraph to find out why, but failed

here is my env

```
{
  "chardet": {
    "version": "3.0.4"
  },
  "cryptography": {
    "version": "2.3.1"
  },
  "idna": {
    "version": "2.7"
  },
  "implementation": {
    "name": "CPython",
    "version": "3.6.6"
  },
  "platform": {
    "release": "10",
    "system": "Windows"
  },
  "pyOpenSSL": {
    "openssl_version": "1010009f",
    "version": "18.0.0"
  },
  "requests": {
    "version": "2.19.1"
  },
  "system_ssl": {
    "version": "100020ff"
  },
  "urllib3": {
    "version": "1.23"
  },
  "using_pyopenssl": true
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What make you think there is a memory leak?

Comment: top -p process_id，the res is increase 5 times after 1 hour, and is still growing
@kcorlidy

Comment: Taskmgr shows memory growing on win10@kcorlidy

Comment: When i use Python2-x, then i found there are 11 can't collect. But zero on Python3-x.

Comment: However, when i used `objgraph` on Python3-x, i found `SplitResult` and `RequestsCookieJar` may be lead to a memory leak.